# How long does Chrome take for HSTS preload list inclusion?

Tags: google-chrome, hsts

Assuming that my domain meets the inclusion requirements, and I successfully submit it to [hstspreload.org](https://hstspreload.org/), then:

1. How long does it take on average until Chrome comes out with a new stable release with my domain preloaded?
2. Is there an easy way to check on the progress?

Comment: According to the docs - _several months_